# Redirect ffmpeg pipe to child process

Tags: c++, windows

How can I redirect a ffmpeg pipe from a process to the child process stdin?

I want to achieve the same thing as piping in cmd:

```
ffmpeg -i test.mov pipe:1 | vlc -
```

I tried:

```
avio_open("pipe:1"); // ffmpeg open pipe to STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE.

// lots of code

STARTUPINFO si;
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES saAttr = {0}; 
saAttr.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES); 
saAttr.bInheritHandle = TRUE; 
saAttr.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL; 

CreatePipe(&hReadPipe, &hWritePipe, &saAttr, 0);

SetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE, hWritePipe);

ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));

si.cb = sizeof(si);
si.dwFlags   = STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
si.hStdInput = hReadPipe;   

CreateProcess(NULL,   // No module name (use command line)
    L"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\VideoLAN\\VLC\\vlc -vv --demux ffmpeg -",        // Command line
    NULL,           // Process handle not inheritable
    NULL,           // Thread handle not inheritable
    TRUE,          // Set handle inheritance to FALSE
    0,              // No creation flags
    NULL,           // Use parent's environment block
    NULL,           // Use parent's starting directory 
    &si,            // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
    &pi )           // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure

// start ffmpeg write to file.
```

But I honestly don't know what I'm doing.

Is there any `GetStdHandle` that doesn't normally print to the console?

Comment: What you have there might work if you are forking a child after capturing the output handle of the parent using GetStdHandle.  But how does the res of your code work?

Comment: John Zwinck: Added more code, anything specific you need to know?

Comment: Now you've hidden the type of your variable `si` (that was shown before your edit!).  I don't know if I'll be able to solve your problem per se, but I think you can make your question better and that will help others help you.

Comment: Use the boilerplate SDK sample code: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Hans Passant: I'm pretty much doing what that sample shows? I don't see anything that I should be doing differently based on that.

Answer (score 1):

You can try creating a pipe:

1. Call [CreatePipe()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365152%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to create a read handle and a write handle
2. Call [SetStdHandle()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686244%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to make the write handle of the pipe your new stdout
3. Specify the read handle of the pipe as hStdInput to CreateProcess()

Update:

if your application uses printf() to print to the STD output console, you will probably need to hack into the stdout struct and replace the handle there. In any case, try stepping into a printf() call that does not redirected correctly and see which handle it uses in the end.

Comment: The wierd thing is that it keep printing a lot of noise to the main console, even though I've redirected STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE.

Comment: The child process doesn't seem to complain that it can't open the pipe anymore atleast. I think the problem is that my app is not writing to the pipe, but for some reason writing to console, even though it was redirected.

Comment: How do I know what pipe:x maps to? where 0 <= x <= 9.